# How do I put two system of equations side by side?

Tags: equations

Title says it all. I've tried this

```
\begin{alignat*}
& \begin{aligned} & \begin{cases}
m \Ddot{x} = m g \cdot sen(\theta) - F_r \\
    m \Ddot{y} = m g \cdot cos(\theta) - N = 0 \\
    I \Ddot{\phi} = \sum \tau = \Vec{R} \times \Vec{F_r}
  \end{cases}\\
  \MoveEqDown
  \end{aligned}
    \Rightarrow
  \begin{aligned}
  & \begin{cases}
  \vspace{1mm}
  m \Ddot{x} = m g \cdot sen(\theta) - \mu \cdot m  g \cdot cos(\theta) \\
    m \Ddot{y} = m g \cdot cos(\theta) - N = 0 \\
    I \Ddot{\phi} = R \cdot \mu \cdot mg \cdot cos(\theta) \cdot sen(\alpha)
  \end{cases} \\
  \MoveEqLeft[-1]
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}
```

It shows like the image posted. That arrow is so annoying, there must be an easier way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want to achieve? You had to nest `aligned` in `cases`, not the reverse. The outer `alignat` was  unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{cases}
       \begin{aligned}
m \Ddot{x} & = m g \cdot \sin(\theta) - F_r, \\
    m \Ddot{y} & = m g \cdot \cos(\theta) - N = 0, \\
    I \Ddot{\phi} & = \sum \tau = \vec{R} \times \Vec{F_r}
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
    \implies\enspace
  \begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
   m \Ddot{x} & = m g \cdot \sin(\theta) - \mu \cdot m g \cdot \cos(\theta), \\
    m \Ddot{y} & = m g \cdot \cos(\theta) - N = 0, \\
    I \Ddot{\phi} & = R \cdot \mu \cdot mg \cdot \cos(\theta) \cdot \sin(\alpha)
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks bro, much appreciated